# ListView- Async task- Loading images

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-imageview

In my application I have a requirement to display Images that are stored in external storage directory. I populate list view with these images. But, if there are too many images say, >10, app runs out of memory. I now understand that I should implement an Async task to achieve this.Can some one help me how do I do this. Should I call the Async class in LisviewAdapter.java or Activity.java? Any example would be greatly helpful.Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your logcat... post some code, so we can really check what's wrong. Also, how big are the images?

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla: Images are captured from device-camera with 8MP.So, they are around 2MB and above. Is 'Asynctask' a correct approach to load images into listview ? pls suggest

Comment: the problem is not that... you don't need an asynctask... what you need is a library like picasso to get the images and resize them (only to show it). 8MP is WAY too much for Android to show it in a single imageview.

Answer (score 2):

Well to Optimize that ,i better suggest you to Use
`Picasso` Library for Loading Images from URL.

Features are :

```
Handling ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
Automatic memory and disk caching.
```

Check this : http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use LazyLoading mechanism to avoid memory issue. Picasso is great library for android to accomplish such kind of task. Just add the line in your adapter instead of setting bitmap to imageview directly:

```
Picasso.with( context ).load( new File(...)).into( imageView3 );
```

Also you have add those into build.gradle file in dependency list:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso: 2.5.2 '
```